# Wordpress Custom PHP contact form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I'm using code from another source but it's very different to what I'm used to coding when using standard HTML/PHP websites. Wordpress seems to have a mind of it's own. Basically I need the contact form's PHP to send the name and email within the body text of the email and not just the persons message. Currently all that comes through is the persons message.

```
<?php

  //response generation function

  $response = "";

  //function to generate response
  function my_contact_form_generate_response($type, $message){

    global $response;

    if($type == "success") $response = "<div class='success'>{$message}</div>";
    else $response = "<div class='error'>{$message}</div>";

  }

  //response messages
  $not_human       = "Human verification incorrect.";
  $missing_content = "Please Fill in all Required Fields.";
  $email_invalid   = "Your Email Address is Invalid.";
  $message_unsent  = "Message was not sent. Please Try Again.";
  $message_sent    = "Thanks! Your message has been sent.";

  //user posted variables
  $name = $_POST['message_name'];
  $email = $_POST['message_email'];
  $message = $_POST['message_text'];
  $human = $_POST['message_human'];

  //php mailer variables
  $to = get_option('admin_email');
  $subject = "New Enquiry Through Mon Voyage Website";
  $headers = 'From: '. $email . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";

  if(!$human == 0){
    if($human != 2) my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $not_human); //not human!
    else {

      //validate email
      if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $email_invalid);
      else //email is valid
      {
        //validate presence of name and message
        if(empty($name) || empty($message)){
          my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);
        }
        else //ready to go!
        {
          $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message), $headers);
          if($sent) my_contact_form_generate_response("success", $message_sent); //message sent!
          else my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $message_unsent); //message wasn't sent
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else if ($_POST['submitted']) my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);

?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What HTML do you have? Are you getting any errors? Have you tried to debug this at all?

Comment: Personally I'd just plug Contact Form 7 in and set up the template to put what I wanted in the email body...

Answer (score 0):

add this in just before if(!$human == 0){:

```
$message.='Name: '.$name.'email: '$email;
```

this is all standard php form checking, 1. function to display a reponse 2. check the $_POST data 3. fail if errors in place 4. if no errors, send email.  Put a few echo's in there and play around with it to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This does not solve the issue you are having directly but instead of writing the code yourself you could use `Contact form 7 plugin` instead. It will save you time and is very quick to implement.

You can get the plugin from [this url](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/).

[Here is](http://contactform7.com/docs/) the documentation for implementing the plugin.

You can add a contact form by adding the short code generated by the plugin to the page you want it to appear like this:

```
[contact-form-7 id="1234" title="Contact form 1"]
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris. I will keep in mind how should an answer be. :)